# check if some SPECIFIC inputs are not empty on a button click using jquery

Tags: jquery, validation, if-statement, for-loop

i have a button and some inputs, i want to let jquery check for me if none of the inputs is empty before doing some action : so this is what i've done :

```
$('#my_button)').click(function() {
if(
for(i=0;i<$('#my _button').parent().prev().children().children().length;i++){){ //this is to check if the inputs exist
$('#my_button').parent().prev().children().children().eq(i).val()!==''; // i've tried .val().is(:empty); but not working too
//so the test fails for somehow ! and the if condition doesn't work
// google chrome developers inspector gives me this error (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token for)
}
){
//do some action
}}
```

and this is my [jsfiddl test](http://jsfiddle.net/zFLqn/) !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It gives you the unexpected token warning on the `for` because *it is* an unexpected token. You can't put `for` loops in the boolean expression of an if statement.

You will need to do something similar to this pseudo-code:

```
$('#my_button').click(function() {
  succeed = true;
  for all of my inputs {
    if(input is empty){
       succeed = false;
    }
  }
  if(succeed) //do stuff
}
```

Comment: i got your idea .. any jsfiddle example ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <div><input id='i1'></div>
   <div><input id='i2'></div>  
  </td>
  <td><button id='my_button'>click me</button></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Script:

```
    $('#my_button').on('click', function() {
        var in1 = $('#i1').val();
        var in2 = $('#i2').val();

        if(in1 != '' && in2 != ''){
               // do something
            }
            else{
              //alert

            }
    }
```

Comment: i must mention that i can't associate any ID with inputs because they are created dynamically ... and it will be a mess if i tried to includ ID's

Comment: and i don't want to disable my button ! i want do some other action ONLY IF all the inputs are empty